# Javascript how to update a cart number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys I've decide to try and build an E-commerce site rather then use Shopify just so i can get some experience, however i am trying to get it so that the cart quantity updates when the user clicks "Add to cart" but i cant seem to get it to work

HTML:

```
<a class="shopping-cart" href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="cart-badge">1</span></a>
<button class="addcart btn btn-danger add-to-cart" type="button">Add to cart</button>
```

Javascript:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".accordion-heading").click(function(){  
             if($(".accordion-body").is(':visible')){  /* check the condition accordion-body is visible or not */
                 $(".accordion-body").slideUp(200);  /*if content is visible then close accordion-body with specific time duration */
               $(".plusminus").text('+')    /* add plus sign */
           }
           else{
               $(this).next(".accordion-body").slideDown(200); /*if content not visible then 
                                                                                                           show the accordion-body */
               $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');  /* add minus sign */
           }
       });
   });
```

I tried to use this example to help me : [Link](https://codepen.io/jonicious/pen/bCilf?q=add%20to%20cart%20&limit=all&type=type-pens)
So I just want it so that then the user clicks the "Add to cart" it will update the counter i have built

But javascript isn't my strongest skill set so any help would be amazing , thanks

Comment: You need to know a Server Language, as well. That example won't help you much. I've built my own shopping cart. Good luck, I'm out.

Comment: @PHPglue Ah yes i understand that but for now i just want to get the basic stuff working like this

Comment: It's going to take you years, if you don't do it right to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added variable to keep track on how many items you have in cart. Every time you click add to cart button variable goes +1 and changes displayed text in span.

```js
var currentItems = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".accordion-heading").click(function(){  
             if($(".accordion-body").is(':visible')){  /* check the condition accordion-body is visible or not */
                 $(".accordion-body").slideUp(200);  /*if content is visible then close accordion-body with specific time duration */
               $(".plusminus").text('+')    /* add plus sign */
           }
           else{
               $(this).next(".accordion-body").slideDown(200); /*if content not visible then 
                                                                                                           show the accordion-body */
               $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');  /* add minus sign */
           }
       });
       $(".add-to-cart").click(function(){
           currentItems++;
           $(".cart-badge").text(currentItems);
       });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="shopping-cart" href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="cart-badge">0</span></a>
<button class="addcart btn btn-danger add-to-cart" type="button">Add to cart</button>
```